# Cat keeps removing collar

Tags: cats, collar

Every time we put a collar on our cat he keeps removing it.  He's pretty much OK with it when it's put on (it doesn't freak him out), he's just stubborn and removes it when we're not looking.  Often we don't find the collar so we have to buy another one.

We want him to have a collar as it's useful to stop fleas and to identify him.  What can we do to make him keep it on?  Are there certain types of collar that are harder for cats to take off?

Comment: Cat collars have to be easy to remove for safety; consider instead, keeping him inside and getting him microchipped. This will reduce his exposure to fleas (which are not stopped by normal collars, and flea collars are *not* safe), and reduce the need for an identifying collar.

Comment: Can you include a photo of the collar?